# Need a html visual editor

Tags: html

I need to write and publish a book on my site.
It is very time consuming to write all the needed tags (paragraphs, line brakes, indents, dialogs...).

Is there any simple application, where I can write a text in visual mode, and publish them on a web page without coding all those tags ?

For example, if I press `Enter` or `Tab` - html brake tag or line indent should be entered.
Hanging text is also important for me, because a lot of dialogs in the book.

I tried with MS Word 2010 (Save As html) - but I'm not satisfied with the final result.

Thanks.

Comment: There are [many HTML editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTML_editors) out there—take your pick. Wikipedia also [compares them for you](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_HTML_editors). You're just looking for a WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a very quick and easy visual HTML editor, the first program that comes to mind would be [Dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver.html).  It's extremely easy to use and the HTML/CSS that it outputs is fairly straight forward. It will give you all the basic customization options that you could be looking for.

Alternatively, you can take the Open Source approach and there are a variety of products that can very easily satisfy your specific needs. There is a good list [here](http://osalt.com/dreamweaver). Of these, my personal choice would be [KompoZer](http://www.kompozer.net/). I've found the output html is relatively good overall for the minimal effort involved.